# How make a table with lua and LuaLaTeX

Tags: tables, luatex, lua

I can't get lua and LuaLaTeX to produce a table, I am missing something in the `tex.sprint` line. I need LuaLaTeX to print the value and I need a new row in the table starting from the new line.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
local a, b, c, d
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
tex.sprint("\\begin{tabular}{lllll}")
    
for i = 1,10
do
a = a + 1 
b = b + 1
c = c + 1
d = d + 1

if ((a + b + c + d) <= 100)
then
tex.sprint("i & a & b & c & d\\")
end
end

tex.sprint("\\end{tabular}")
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the line:

```tex
tex.sprint("i & a & b & c & d\\")
```

into

```
tex.sprint("i & a & b & c & d\\\\")
```

since Lua changes `\\` in a string into a single backslash, but you need two backslashes for a line end.

Comment: I think he want values  of variables, so what he needs is `tex.sprint(i.."&"..a.."&"..b.."&"..c.."&"..d.."\\\\")`

Comment: You could also use `[[`double bracket quotes`]]`. Then you wouldn't need to double the backslashes